# Office-js: How I can reply automatically with Outlook Web Add-in?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm using Outlook Web Add-in. I need a way to send an email automatically. Something similar to this:

```js
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
item.displayReplyAllForm("Default Message");
```

but without showing the Reply Form. I need to send a message directly and 
maybe only show a message like "replying... please wait" or something similar when I click the button.

How I can do that? Please help and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the JavaScript library directly. You would need to use Microsoft Graph API to handle sending the message. You can find instruction on how to do this in the documentation under [Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

Comment: How? What do you mean? Can you give me an example about how I can send the email with the MS Graph API?

Comment: You'll need to use Microsoft Graph's `Send` method. The link in the answer explains how to obtain a token. Then Graph method you're looking for is documented at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send

Comment: Could we understand what your scenario is for which you need to send the message directly instead of having the user give an option to send or not like  with using the displayReplyAllForm?

Comment: Yes, I need to send the message directly, In VSTO it can be possible, but now is limited to show the ReplyAll form ¿It can be possible?. Thanks @MarcLaFleur-MSFT for your answer, let me check what I can do with that.

Comment: The problem with MS Graph is they ask you to log in and allow to Send the email, Is almost the same that show it the reply form, I need a clean reply message without confirmations and without ask permissions, just like VSTO technology.

Comment: Please look at the link I provided. Outlook can return a token for Graph for the current user's mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of solution one is with graph and another is with exchange api. For graph you need to little bit of extra work to get the token and auth flow working.

The other approach is to use exchange API, you don't need to do anything to do these calls you already have the authentication setup needed for you in dong this call.

Please see this documentation for the more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633704(v=exchg.80).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

Answer (score 0):

If you want a client only solution you can directly call the Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync API (refer documentation here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook)

To construct the soap request to be used in makeEWSRequest, you can use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Note that makeEWSRequest is not supported in mobile clients.

You should ideally request for a graph token using getCallbackTokenAsync API and then use the graph APIs with the token to send the email. This should work on all clients and is a preferred way to accomplish this scenario.